# double CSS3 transform after a single CSS3 transform

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation

I have a HTML5, jQuery card memory game where you match cards by flipping them two at a time. I would like to have an animation play out when two cards are matched, but because I have already applied `"transform: rotationY(180deg)"`to the flipped cards it bugs out.

Card HTML

```
<div id="card1" class="card">
    <figure class="front">
        <img src="front.jpg">
    </figure>
    <figure class="back">
        <img src="back.jpg">
    </figure>
</div>
```

First the player reveals this and I add the "flipped" class to it.

```
.flipped {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

Then I remove "flipped" class and add the class scaleOut. The rotateY is there to maintain the rotation so that the right side keeps being showed to the player and the scale is there to hide the card.

```
.scaleOut {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg) scale(0.0);
}
```

This doesn't seem to work even though just adding the flipped class successfully flips the cards. Chrome seems to run the animations, but plays them instantly while Firefox doesn't play the scale animation at all.

Here is the code where I change the classes. It adds and removes classes just fine.

```
 $(#card1).removeClass('flipped');
 $(#card1).addClass('scaleOut');
```

Card and board CSS

```
#board {
    padding-top: 10px;
    width: 600px;
    height: 450px;
    background-color: rgb(228, 223, 208);
    -webkit-perspective: 1000px;
    perspective: 1000px;
}

.card {
    float:left;
    width: 106px;
    height: 100px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #cfcfcf;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s;
    transition: transform 1s;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have a reason as to why it happens this way but it seems to be working fine when `scale(1)` is set on the `transform` within `.flipped` class. Since `scale(1)` is the initial state and the card should be visible when it is flipped but not matched, I don't think adding this to the `transform` property should cause any problems.(*I will update the answer when I manage to find the reason for this behavior.*)

This works fine in the latest versions of both Chrome, Firefox and Edge.

**Note:** The snippet was prepared before you had updated your CSS for board and card into question. The CSS is a bit different but the solution should still work for your case.

```js
var temp1 = $('#card1');
temp1.on('click', function() {
  temp1.addClass('flipped');
  setTimeout(function() {
    temp1.removeClass('flipped');
    temp1.addClass('scaleOut');
  }, 2500);
})
''
```

```css
.flipped {
  transform: rotateY(180deg) scale(1);
}
.scaleOut {
  transform: rotateY(180deg) scale(0);
}
.front {
  background: yellowgreen;
}
.back {
  background: green;
}
.card {
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: all 1s;
}
figure {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: 0;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.back {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="card1" class="card">
  <figure class="front">
    <img src="front.jpg">
  </figure>
  <figure class="back">
    <img src="back.jpg">
  </figure>
</div>
```